# Code logic javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

I am using jQuery isotope plugin to sort and filter elements. Elements are products having multiple filter groups. I am facing one issue, I need to filter products with multi select filter attribute in same group example:

Filter Groups: Gender, Product category, Product material.

Sample select : Men, Bag, Leather.

Above sample works fine.

But I need something like

New filter selection: Men, Bag, Wallet, leather, Rexin.

If you notice Bag and Wallet are from same group. And leather and Rexin are from same group.

for doing this I would need filter value to be passed like

filtervalue - 
.men.bag.leather,.men.wallet.leather,.men.bag.rexin,.men.wallet.rexin.

This sounds easy, but I am finding difficult to code this.

I have array of each filter group, which I am updating when the user selects or deselects a particular filter

So essentially, what I need is combining or grouping multiple filter arrays into one string with each group containing every element from each array and each group separated with a comma.

Arrays in javascript:

```
var gender = ['.men'];
var type = ['.bag','.wallet'];
var material = ['.leather','.rexin'];
Output:
".men.bag.leather,.men.wallet.leather,.men.bag.rexin,.men.wallet.rexin"
```

Hope I am clear on what I need.

Help much appreciated.

Update:

Since the filters can vary on different products, I am unable to use hardcoded variables like gender, type etc. So instead I am using filters array

```
var selectedFilter = [];
selectedFilter['gender'] = ['.men'];
selectedFilter['type'] = ['.bag','.wallet'];
selectedFilter['platform'] = ['.leather','.rexin'];
```

Need Output like, 
".men.bag.leather,.men.wallet.leather,.men.bag.rexin,.men.wallet.rexin"

Need some function which I can directly pass one array variable.
like

```
combine(selectedFilter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use combination algorithm.

```js
function combine(object) {
    function c(part, index) {
        array[index].forEach(function (a) {
            var p = part.concat([a]);
            if (p.length === array.length) {
                r.push(p.join(''));
                return;
            }
            c(p, index + 1);
        });
    }

    var array = Object.keys(object).map(function (k) { return object[k]; }),
        r = [];

    c([], 0);
    return r.join();
}

var selectedFilter = {                         // use an object instead of 
        gender: ['.men'],                      // an array with properties
        type: ['.bag','.wallet'],
        platform: ['.leather','.rexin']
    };

console.log(combine(selectedFilter));
```